# Processing a large data frame in chunks to avoid running out of memory

Tags: r

I did some searching and all the posts I found on this are concerned with either reading in a large file into R or recommend using group_by and then performing summary calculations. However, I'm not trying to apply summary calculations on groups, initially I'm processing each individual line item using stringr, separate and gather/spread operations.

I have a dataframe with ~5M rows starting with ~10 features but after desired pre processing using gather and spread should end up being about 5M * 50 data frame.

Each time I try to pass my data frame through a dplyr chain I run out of memory.

So, I tried breaking up up into chunks and using the foreach package to process in parallel since I'm using RStudio on a hosted Lunix server with 4 cores.

The gist of my approach is below. My question is, given that this must be a common problem, is there a 'conventional' or recommended way of approaching this problem?

Here's what my code looks like. I'm seeking recommendations for a more elegant solution if one exists:

```
(userbase is my dataframe with ~5M * 10 in size)
chunk <- 1000000 # break into chunks of 1M each
n <- nrow(userbase)
r  <- rep(1:ceiling(n / chunk), each = chunk, length.out = nrow(userbase) )[1:n]
d <- split(userbase, r)

# parallel processing
library(foreach)
library(doParallel) 
cl<-makeCluster(parallel::detectCores() - 1) # setup parallel backend to use all available processors minus 1
registerDoParallel(cl)
foreach(i = 1:length(d), .packages = c("tidyverse", "lubridate")) %dopar% {

  p <- do stuff... 

  iter <- paste0("pdata", i)         

  saveRDS(p, paste0("rds_files/pdata_loop/", iter, ".rds"))) # save each chunk as rds else run out of memory

  return(1) #forget whatever had in memory since now saved as rds file which can be read in later
}

stopCluster(cl)
iterations <- list.files("rds_files/pdata_loops")
pdata <- list resulting from reading through each saved rds file
processed_data <- do.call("rbind", pdata)
```

Is my approach sound or is there a easier way?

Comment: (1) Loading all of `tidyverse` into each node might not be necessary ... are you `ggplot`ing in all of them? You can reduce a little memory (and start-up time) that way. (To be honest, I do not have but would be interesting in seeing memory usage with `library(tidyverse)`. It's an "unsubstantiated concern" of mine. Another day.)

Comment: (2) Are you confident that your *"do stuff"* is efficient by itself? Since you're dealing with `dplyr` chains and a lot of data, it might be making a lot more copies than you want it to. Perhaps a `data.table`-based solution would help memory utilization. (I've also seen a slight mis-step in code cause an explosion in memory, so profiling this portion might be necessary.)

Comment: (3) Do smaller `chunk` sizes help? Do you know when it runs out of memory? Keep in mind that `(ncores-1)*chunk` might still be too big for your processing, perhaps fewer parallels and/or smaller `chunk`?

Comment: In general, the gist is sound: break up, process individually, save elsewhere; then load all and do.call/rbind ... yup, the methodology looks sound to me. I'd say mess with `ncores` and `chunk` (to reduce instantaneous memory usage), look at `data.table` if you can afford the learning curve, and step into your *"do stuff"* to see where you can reduce your footprint.

Comment: Hi thanks for feedback. Using smaller chunk sizes of 100K as opposed to 1M allowed me to finally complete the loop successfully. RE data table and if my code is efficent - probably not! I'm sure it could be optimized. I just love the readability of dplyr chains. Anyway, thank for validating that the gist of my approach is sound

Comment: I agree that readability is a good thing (for auditing and maintainability). FYI, you can use magrittr's `%>%` with data.table just as easily, see [here](https://martinctc.github.io/blog/using-data.table-with-magrittr-pipes-best-of-both-worlds/) for an example. Depending on how important and repeating this process is to you, besides buying more RAM you might want to look at [profiling your memory usage](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/profmem/vignettes/profmem.html). (The author of `profmem` also wrote `future`, if it matters.)